# How to pass ISO dates to Symfony

Tags: symfony, validation, datetime, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to change how dates get passed to the back-end because they can come from all sorts of timezones, but get interpreted as the local timezone.

If I pass a date such as `dateConducted: "2019-12-07T04:35:00.000Z"` back, I get the following error in the response:

```
dateConducted: {errors: ["This value is not valid."],…}
  children: {date: {children: {year: [], month: [], day: []}}, time: {children: {hour: [], minute: []}}}
    date: {children: {year: [], month: [], day: []}}
    time: {children: {hour: [], minute: []}}
  errors: ["This value is not valid."]
    0: "This value is not valid."
```

I can't see anything in the project files that require a date to be broken down into limited components, so I assume it's in Symfony somewhere. At the moment, it's pretty magic to me because I don't understand what the requirements are. I've found [Symfony 2.8 - Reference / Constraints / DateTime](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/DateTime.html) which seems to suggest that a datetime string should work, yet it doesn't.

[Symfony 2.8 - Reference / Types / DateType Field #input](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/date.html#input) also says:

> input¶
> **type**: `string` **default**: `datetime`
>
> The format of the *input* data - i.e. the format that the date is stored on your underlying object. Valid values are:
>
> - string (e.g. 2011-06-05)
> - datetime (a DateTime object)
> - array (e.g. array('year' => 2011, 'month' => 06, 'day' => 05))
> - timestamp (e.g. 1307232000)
>
> The value that comes back from the form will also be normalized back into this format.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Type` class for the entity being saved, e.g. `AppointmentType.php`, change

```php
->add('dateConducted')
```

to

```php
->add('dateConducted', null, [
  'widget' => 'single_text',
])
```

Symfony will then treat the input as a single value instead of two arrays of date parts and time parts.